# How to get list of data found using patterns

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to filter data in an array with the help of a pattern `\d\.\d`. The elements in the array might sometimes consist of strings as well. I try to use the `re.findall` function to get a list of the decimal numbers within my strings in the array but my code doesn't recognise all decimal numbers.

My code is as below -

```
import re 
import itertools
str1 = "2.7"
str2 = ".3"
str3 = "."
str4 = "2"
str5 = "sushruth" 
x = [str1,str2,str3,str4,str5]
y = []
for a in x:
    z = re.findall(r'\d\.\d',a)
    if z:
        print(z)
```

The output is only `[2.7]` whereas I need to also get `[.3]`. What change is required in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
z = re.findall(r'\d?\.\d',a)
```

Comment: Thanks. The output i get looks somewhat like `[2.7] [.3]` is there any way to get all the detected patterns in a list or array like `[2.7,.3]` ?

Comment: @Sushruth `[e for e in x if re.match(r'\d?.\d', e)]`